# beautifulsoup multiple keyword from csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a csv file with 2 column A and B, and I want scrap all the file with beautifulsoup

The url is composed like this : http://.../search?info=A&who=B
how to create a loop?

my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import csv

with open('input.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
    for row in reader:
        url = ".../search?info={}&who={}".format(row[0], row[1])
        response = requests.get(url)
        html = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

        for p in soup.find_all(class_="crd"):
            b = p.find(class_="info")
            if b['data-info'] is not None:
            j = json.loads(b['data-info'])
            data= p.h2.a.string
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop?

Comment: And why would you need beautifulsoup if the response is a csv already.
Please give a sample output of that request and what you are trying to do.

Comment: show me your csv a couple of lines like 5 maybe

Comment: It's better to use `.DictReader()` in order to be able to call the desired items using the `header` like `row['header']` instead of using that hardcoded way.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('input.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
  for row in reader:
    url = url = ".../search?info={}&who={}".format(row[0], row[1])
    #rest of your logic
```

Comment: i have update my code and i have File "jo.py", line 8, in <module>
    for row in reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: It was not indented. I have edited it. can you check now?                                    for statement should be inside the with block